# C# Replace everything except two cases

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation

how can i do something like this.

```
new Regex("([^my]|[^test])").Replace("Thats my working test", "");
```

I would get this:

```
my test
```

But i would get a empty string, because everything would be replaced with none.

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Why use a regex? Are you looking for a pattern or specific, known words?

Comment: Two simple calls to String.Replace would be enough.

Comment: Something is wrong. You want to replace everyting except two cases (I guess that these cases are `my` and `test`). So the output should be `my test`. What I'm missing?

Comment: It fails because `[^my]` does not mean "not the word 'my'", but "any character except 'm' or 'y'"

Comment: Example was wrong. sorry. i would replace everything except the words my and test so that i get `my test`

Answer (score 5):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
new Regex("(?!\b(?:my|test)\b)\b(\w+)\s*").Replace("Thats my working test", "");

//=> my test
```

Your use of negation in character class is incorrect here: `([^my]|[^test])`

Since inside character class every character is checked individually not as a string.

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/iA1eJ0/2)

Comment: Ah thanks. But my example was false. I mean this result: "my test". I would replace everything except "my" and "test". Thats was the plan. I could use `(my|test)` instead but thats wrong for this. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex replacement:

```
new Regex("\b(?!my|test)\w+\s?").Replace("Thats my working test", "");
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/sN3jX0/2)!

- `\b` Asserts the position before our word to check.
- `(?!` Negative lookahead - asserts that our match is **NOT**:
- - `my|test` The character sequences **"my" or "test"**.
- `)`
- `\w+` Then match the word because it's what we want.
- `\s?` And scrap the whitespace after it if it's there, too.

Answer (score -1):

I can suggest to use next regEx :

```
var res = new Regex(@"my(?:$|[\s\.;\?\!,])|test(?:$|[\s\.;\?\!,])").Replace("Thats my working test", "");
```

Upd: Or even simplier:

```
var res = new Regex(@"my($|[\s])|test($|[\s])").Replace("Thats my working test", "");
```

Upd2: If you don't know what word you'll use you can do it even more flexible:

```
private string ExeptWords(string input, string[] exept){
   string tmpl = "{0}|[\s]";
   var regexp = string.Join((exept.Select(s => string.Format(tmpl, s)),"|");
   return new Regex(regexp).Replace(("Thats my working test", "");
}
```